# Hibernate error: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named HibernateEjemplo1

Tags: java, hibernate, java-19

I'm a programming student and this is my first contact with Hibernate.

When trying to make a program with netbeans 16 and JDK 19, using Hibernate to connect to a SQL database I get the following error.

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named HibernateEjemplo1
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
        at test.HolaMundoHibernate.main(HolaMundoHibernate.java:12)
    Command execution failed.
```

Following an internet tutorial I have done the following:

1. I have created the database called **test** and the table called **persona** with SQL.
2. I have created a java Maven project, called **HibernateExample1** with Netbeans 16 and JDK 19.
3. I have modified the **pom.xml** file to add dependencies. I have only added the ones highlighted in blue, the rest have been added by themselves by doing **clean & build** in the project.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>mx.com.gm</groupId>
        <artifactId>HibernateEjemplo1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
            <exec.mainClass>HibernateEjemplo1</exec.mainClass>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.28</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.core</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.asm</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.antlr</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jpql</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.persistence</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

4. I have created the **persistence.xml** file

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence version="2.2" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence_2_2.xsd">
     <persistence-unit name="HibernateEjemplo1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
       <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
       <class>mx.com.gm.domain.Persona</class>
       <properties>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
       </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
   ```
5. I have created the file **log4j2.xml**

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Configuration status="INFO">
       <Appenders>
           <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
               <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
           </Console>
       </Appenders>
       <Loggers>
           <Logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" additivity="false">
               <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
           </Logger>
           <Logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="trace" additivity="false">
               <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
           </Logger>
           <Root level="info">
               <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
           </Root>
       </Loggers>
   </Configuration>
   ```
6. I have created the class **Persona.java** which has the same attributes as my SQL table.

   ````java
   package mx.com.gm.domain;

   import java.io.Serializable;
   import javax.persistence.*;

   @Entity
   @Table(name = "persona")
   public class Persona implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Column(name = "id_persona")
       @Id
       private int idPersona;

       private String nombre;

       private String apellido;

       private String email;

       private String telefono;

       public Persona() {
       }

       public int getIdPersona() {
           return idPersona;
       }

       public void setIdPersona(int idPersona) {
           this.idPersona = idPersona;
       }

       public String getNombre() {
           return nombre;
       }

       public void setNombre(String nombre) {
           this.nombre = nombre;
       }

       public String getApellido() {
           return apellido;
       }

       public void setApellido(String apellido) {
           this.apellido = apellido;
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return email;
       }

       public void setEmail(String email) {
           this.email = email;
       }

       public String getTelefono() {
           return telefono;
       }

       public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
           this.telefono = telefono;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Empleados{" + "idPersona=" + idPersona + ", nombre=" + nombre + ", apellido=" + apellido + 
                   ", email=" + email + ", telefono=" + telefono + '}';
       }

   }
       ```
   ````
7. And finally, I have created the class **HolaMundoHibernate.java** to run the program.

   ```java
   package test;

   import java.util.List;
   import javax.persistence.*;
   import mx.com.gm.domain.Persona;


   public class HolaMundoHibernate {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           String hql = "SELECT p FROM Persona p";
           EntityManagerFactory fabrica = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernateEjemplo1");
           EntityManager entityManager = fabrica.createEntityManager();

           Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql);
           List<Persona> personas = query.getResultList();

           for (Persona p : personas) {
               System.out.println("Persona: " + p);
           } 

       }
   }
   ```

When I run the program I get the following error:
**No Persistence provider for EntityManager named HibernateEjemplo1**

The structure of my project is as follows.

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMrWt.png)

Any help is welcome.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do believe every third Q last month(s) related to HBN/JPA was raised due to incompatibility between JPA2.x and JPA3. Remove everything containing "eclipse" and "jpa" from project dependencies, replace everywhere "javax.persistence" by "jakarta.persistence"

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Robert . Much more readable than before.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyB.Panfilov , I have tried as you say, but it doesn't work for me at the moment. 

I'm starting to think that maybe the xml urls are failing. I will continue to investigate what you say about the incompatibility between JPA2.x and JPA3.

Comment: in JPA3 eclipse foundation developers renamed package name from "javax.persistence" to "jakarta.persistence" which in turn caused a lot of incompatibilities between old and new libraries, for example yours `HolaMundoHibernate` uses `EntityManagerFactory` from `javax.persistence` while `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider` inherits `jakarta.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider`

Comment: I was able to solve that problem. Thanks for your help. 
I needed to change this in the persistence.xml:
`<persistence version="3.0" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence
            https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">`
Now I have another error, the root cannot be resolved.
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.sqm.UnknownEntityException: Could not resolve root entity 'persona'`

Comment: I am still learning. I will investigate until it is solved. ;)